# How to remove parentheses with the text inside and some text at the end of the string

Tags: regex, google-sheets

Text: `2x4 (69x420 cm) Apple Banana Orange Grape`

Function: `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"^.+ Apple Banana")`

Current Result:

```
2x4 (69x420 cm) Apple Banana
```

Desired result: `2x4 Apple Banana`

Comment: Why `One Two`? There is no such a substring in the text. How can you get `2x1` in the current result if your text only contains `2x4`? What are your regex specs?

Comment: I think it depends on you exact definition of the problem.   For example, do you allow nested parentheses?   How do you handle an unmatched parenthesis?

Comment: Sorry I meant `2x4` and `Apple Banana`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to remove parentheses and the text inside?

use:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1; " (\(.+\))"; )
```

[image]

---

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(A1, " (\(.+\))", ), ".+ Apple Banana")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use

```js
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "^(.*?)\s*\([^()]*\)\s*(Apple Banana).*", "$1 $2")
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/tTWBKJ/1).

[image]

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^()]*                   any character except: '(', ')' (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Apple Banana             'Apple Banana'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```